# How to search for a specific file in the source control of TFS inside a particular selected project?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, full-text-search

Code:

```
string spName = "usp_Test_Procedure.sql";
var tfsPp = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.SingleProject, false);
tfsPp.ShowDialog();
_tfs = tfsPp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection;
if (tfsPp.SelectedProjects.Any())
{
     _selectedTeamProject = tfsPp.SelectedProjects[0];
}
string selectedProjectName = _selectedTeamProject.Name;
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(_tfs.Uri);
var vsStore = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var project = "project";
var branchVersion = "1.0.0";
var folders = vsStore.GetItems("$/" + selectedProjectName + "/*", RecursionType.Full);
```

How to **search for a specific file** in the **source control of TFS** inside a **particular selected project and also selected branchversion** in the dropdown menu by the user from the c# UI winforms application?

Here the file I need to search is `usp_Test_Procedure.sql` which is present in the following path

```
$/selectedProjectName/project/1.0.0/UI/Scripts/usp_Test_Procedure.sql
```

Actually I am getting the above path from the foolowing code:

```
folders.Items[29956].ServerItem
```

But I need to know **how to search for a specific file** in the source control of TFS inside a particular selected project and also selected branchversion? Thanks.

Comment: Can somebody provide me a solution or suggestion how to proceed..Thanks

Comment: What's the problem with what you're doing?  Does it not work?

Comment: I want to search a file which is present inside the tfs project folder from c# winforms app. I need the full server path of source control and not local mapped path.Thanks.

Comment: I'm not totally clear what your problem is - can't you just use what you have, maybe in conjunction with the `GetItem' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138919.aspx) method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search by content and name you can create a workspace and "get" that specific version locally. Then use the built in search in your OS or in Visual Studio to find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 46):

Install TFS Power Tools, on Source Control windows click with right button on Team Project or branch, on context menu choose Find > Find by Wildcard, just search files by names, not content.

Comment: What if you want to find by content?

Comment: @ArthurSwails you can't search by content using this tool! For that you need to install an extension called Code Search from Microsoft, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-code-search

Comment: Thanks. This really ought to be a standard option in VS.