# Team Foundation Server find a folder

Tags: tfs, tfvc

[image: TFS project tree]

Hello, I am struggling to find a folder in TFS by search. 
Is there any way to find not only code but folders and file names?

Thanks!

**UPD:** [I don't see this folder in the search result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Dx3.png)

I am using (TFS2017)TFVC as version control and the Web/VS2015 as a client.

Comment: Which version of TFS and what is the client you are using (web/Visual Studio version ...)?

Comment: I am using (TFS2017)TFVC as version control and the Web/VS2015 as a client.

Answer (score 0):

For TFS 2017, you can use [Code Search](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/search/code/get-started) if it's been configured by your TFS admin.

For earlier versions, the easiest way is going to be to grab a copy of the source code to a local workspace and then search via the Windows file explorer or via a quickie PowerShell script.

Comment: I need to search through the TFS Content and find particular folder and file by name.

Comment: @AntonHeck There isn't the feature to search out folder in TFS web portal, you can search folder from local workspace as Daniel mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install TFS Power Tools.
2. Menu Source Control > Find > Find by Wildcard ...
3. Enter file or directory name.

Based on [How to search for a specific file in the source control of TFS inside a particular selected project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546712/how-to-search-for-a-specific-file-in-the-source-control-of-tfs-inside-a-particul)